# How can I use node API like spawn to run rosbag?

Tags: node.js, rust, electron, ros, rosbag

I want to use Node or Rust in Electron or Tauri to execute some command commands,like

```bash
$ rosbag info xxxx
```

and in Node I call rosbag with spawn function and the result is right, but when I build app, I get error

```js
const command = spawn('rosbag', ['info', 'xxxxx']);

command .stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log('data',data.toString())
})
```

I try the rosbag path like:

```js
const command = spawn('/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rosbag', ['info', 'xxxxx']);

command .stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log('data',data.toString())
})
```

In the Rust:

```rust
fn get_bag_info(file_path: &str) -> String {    
    let output = Command::new("rosbag")
                   .arg("info")
                   .arg(file_path)
                   .output()
                   .expect("error while running tauri application");   
    return String::from_utf8(output.stdout).unwrap();
}
```

In the electron run :

```
 pnpm start
```

[image]

When I make after, get error

```
pnpm make
```

[image]

In the tauri --- dev

[image]

In the tauri --- build

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it again, When I build , I get like the same error